# Use of the definite article

Tags: articles-definis, absence-d-article

I came across this sentence the other day:

> Dès que je parle de sport, tu penses tout de suite au football

Is it grammatically correct? If so, why is the word 'sport' used without a definite article while the word 'football' is used with one?

Answer (score 4):

Not only is it grammatically correct, but it's the most idiomatic way to phrase the sentence.

It would be weird with "*du sport*", it would imply you're taking about a specific sport, but then the rest of the sentence would not make any sense.

Here "*sport*" means "sports" in general, any sport. That's why the speaker has an issue with the listener only thinking of football when other sports exist.

But even for other topics, it's very common with "*parler de*" to use indefinite articles, since it's an "open" topic of conversation.

Comment: When you say "Le sport est une chose dont il ne parle jamais." you are really talking about sport in general; it follows that you can say as well "Quand je parle du sport…". Those two constructions  are not quite synonymous. ex.  « Les ennemis du sport sont terribles : ils nous obligent à parler du sport.  [Le sport, l'ascèse, le plaisir: éthique et poétique du sport ... -1990](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_sport_l_asc%C3%A8se_le_plaisir/H4bpxo44x54C?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22parler+du+sport%22&pg=PA6&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 2):

"Parler de sport" means "to speak about a particular sport, any sport, or about several sports". "Parler du sport" ("de le sport") means "to speak generally about sport, without any sport having a central interest in the discussion". Both possibilities are correct in the sentence under scrutiny.

There is a synonymoue expression for "parler de sport"; it is "parler sport".